# div not stretching horizontally to contain children

Tags: css, html

I have a setup similar to the one found in this fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/ysb9sfgr/

As you will see, the containing div will not extend to all the children.

```
<div class="parent">
```

How do I make the parent stretch?

Comment: You can add `display:table` to the `.parent` - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ysb9sfgr/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block;` to `div.parent`

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kzr7v1k9/)

```
div.parent {
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: #f00;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: So simple, I tried like everything else, display table, table-cell etc.
THANKS!

Comment: @plazm make sure you accept the answer to give the author credit.

Comment: @ShawnErquhart I know, but at the time I could not accept due to the time rule.